# How to join 2 tabels or more in java/hibernate/mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my application I have four tabels -

- 'customer'  | customer_id PK, ...
- 'office'    | office_id PK, ...
- 'car'       | car_id PK, office_id FK, ...
- 'rental'    | rental_id PK, customer_id FK, car_id FK, ...

I write the Entities for Car and Office

```
@Entity
public class Car {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int car_id;

private int office_id;
...

@Entity
public class Office {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int office_id;
...
```

I retrive data from database using Hibernate and JPA, so I writed CarRepository to make queries

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {

@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.car_type = ?1")
List<Car> findCarByType(String type);

@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.brand = ?1")
List<Car> findCarByBrand(String brand);

@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.model = ?1")
List<Car> findCarByModel(String model);

@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.price = ?1")
List<Car> findCarByPrice(int price);

@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM Office o, Car c WHERE c.office_id = o.office_id")
List<Office> findCarOffice();
```

}

This is my car controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/cars")
public class CarController {

@Autowired
private CarRepository carRepository;

List<Car> cars;

@GetMapping(path = "/get")
public String getAllCars(ModelMap modelMap) {

    cars = carRepository.findAll();
    modelMap.addAttribute("cars", cars);
    return "car";
}
```

My view "car" showing information about cars like type of car, model etc. And at to this point everythink
works fine but I must retrive and print 'city' from Table "office" for each cars where they are. 
My question is how can I do that? How can I join tables? What is a best approach?

Should I use Anotation @ManyToOne ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. If someone will be have this kind of problem, solution is simple.
In CarRepository you can write:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {

@Query(value = "SELECT c.car_id, c.office_id, c.car_type, c.brand, c.model, 
c.production_year, c.production_year, c.horsepower, c.seats, c.price, o.city FROM 
Office o, Car c WHERE c.office_id = o.office_id")
List<Object[]> findCarOffice();
}
```

And you can show this data in Controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getcaroffice")
@ResponseBody
public Iterable<Object[]> getAllCars() {

    Iterable<Object[]> carOffice = carRepository.findCarOffice();
    return carOffice;
}
```